# How can I add a global keydown event listener in Dioxus)?

Tags: rust, webassembly, dioxus

I'm currently trying out [dioxus](https://dioxuslabs.com/) for rust, and I'm trying to figure out how to handle a global keyboard down event.

I want to use the arrow keys to move images back and forth:

Here's my code so far:

```rs
use dioxus::{events::*, prelude::*};
use log::{info, LevelFilter};

/**
 * Specify <link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="src/assets" />
 * in the index.html to copy the files!!
 *
 * You'll see them in the dist directory!
 */

fn main() {
    dioxus_logger::init(LevelFilter::Info).expect("failed to init logger");
    dioxus::web::launch(app);
}

fn app(cx: Scope) -> Element {
    let mut index = use_state(&cx, || 1);

    let change_evt = move |evt: KeyboardEvent| match evt.key.as_str() {
        "ArrowRight" => index += 1,
        "ArrowLeft" => index -= 1,
        _ => {}
    };

    let url = format!("/assets/img/wallpaper/1042/0{}.jpg", index);
    cx.render(rsx!(img {
        src: "{url}",
        onkeydown: change_evt,
    }))
}
```

In JavaScript would've been something like

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (evt) => {
 // Do magic
}
```

I've tried following the [calculator example](https://github.dev/DioxusLabs/dioxus/blob/482ae5e395a7e8c5bcefc98f47d8f6c83f8c214a/examples/calculator.rs#L13) but can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I decided to give Yew a shot. I'm just using these as pet projects to learn Rust. Yew apparently had more documentation

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing in Yew.

I used wasm_bindgen and web_sys. This could potentially work for Dioxus

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::{prelude::Closure, JsCast, UnwrapThrowExt};
use web_sys::window;

    use_effect(move || {
        let callback = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |e: web_sys::KeyboardEvent| {
            let key = e.key();
            let key_str = key.as_str();
            match key_str {
                "ArrowLeft" => {
                  // Do something here
                }
                "ArrowRight" => {
                  // Do something here
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);

        win.add_event_listener_with_callback("keydown", callback.as_ref().unchecked_ref())
            .unwrap();

        move || {
            win.remove_event_listener_with_callback("keydown", callback.as_ref().unchecked_ref())
                .unwrap();
        }
    });
```

Here's part of the cargo.toml

```ini
[dependencies]
web-sys = { version = "0.3.60", features = ['console'] }
wasm-bindgen = { version = "0.2.83" }
```

Comment: @Nick Garfield check this answer

Answer (score 1):

`onkeydown` does not seem to work as a callback passed to an image. Wrap it in a `div`.

I placed an extra button there because, for some reason, the keyboard event callbacks did not register until I interacted with the app somehow (tried it in the browser).

```rust
fn app(cx: Scope) -> Element {
    let mut index = use_state(&cx, || 1);

    let change_evt = move |evt: KeyboardEvent| {
        log::info!("{index}{}", evt.key);
        match evt.key.as_str() {
            "ArrowRight" => index += 1,
            "ArrowLeft" => index -= 1,
            _ => {}
        }
    };

    let url = format!("/assets/img/wallpaper/1042/0{}.jpg", index);
    cx.render(rsx!(
        img {
            src: "{url}",
        }
        div {
            class: "display",
            onkeydown: change_evt,
            button {
                class: "but",
                onclick: move |evt| {
                    println!("{evt:?}");
                    info!("{evt:?}");
                },
                "Press me!"
            },
        },
    ))   
}
```

Comment: Hi susitsm. Thank you very much for helping out . The reason why you need a button is because that would focus the div, and then it would let you trigger the onkeydown. This means that the onkeydown is registered locally. I've also tried extracting your src to a separate variable as I had on my question and it worked!

Comment: I believe another solution could be to register the event in the index.html file and somehow signal it back to dioxus.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It works with your format string too.

Comment: @JoseA how did you register onkeydown globally? I can't seem to connect it to the global document, only to a div.

Comment: @NickGarfield
I wasn't able to do it with Dioxus. I ended up migrating to Yew instead. But I think it is not Dioxus nor Yew dependent, as it's using web_sys. I'm going to post an answer to show you what I have in Yew

Answer (score 0):

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
active-win-pos-rs = "0.8.3"
dioxus = "0.4.3"
dioxus-desktop = "0.4.3"
dioxus-html = { version = "0.4.3", features = ["serialize", "native-bind"] }
wry = { version = "0.28.0", default-features = false, features = ["protocol", "file-drop"] }
```

main.rs

```
use active_win_pos_rs::get_active_window;
use dioxus::prelude::*;
use dioxus_desktop;
use wry::application::keyboard::ModifiersState;

fn main() {
    dioxus_desktop::launch(App);
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
fn App(cx: Scope) -> Element {
    dioxus_desktop::use_global_shortcut(cx, (ModifiersState::SUPER, KeyCode::Q), || {
        match get_active_window() {
            Ok(active_window) => {
                if active_window.process_id == std::process::id() as u64 {
                    std::process::exit(0);
                }
            }
            Err(e) => panic!("{:#?}", e),
        }
    });

    render!(div{"hello"})
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you comment it a bit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).